# How to add Autocomplete to a Masked Text Box?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, autocomplete, maskedtextbox

In .Net, there is the MaskedTextBox and there is the TextBox which has an autocomplete member.  Autocomplete doesn't seem to be available for MaskedTextBox.  How do you get MaskedTextBox working with autocomplete?

I am attempting to do this in Visual Basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option is to create a custom control which inherits from MastedTextBox or TextBox and add the missing behavior.

Or to create a control which encapsulates a TextBox but adds your functionality.

I would take a textbox and add the masking, because thats easier than adding the auto-complete.